# How can an iterative algorithm be controlled dynamically?

Tags: design, algorithms, functional-programming, scala

Suppose we need an iterative algorithm for mathematical optimisation. Each iteration takes a long and random time.  After each iteration, a stopping condition is checked for the iterate *x*, based on some pre-defined parameter *b*. An example is "Stop if  *||grad(x)|| < b*",  based on the objective's gradient at *x*.

Here's is an extremely simplified  "algorithm" in pseudo-Scala

```
val f = (a: Dbl, b: Dbl) => { 
def go(x: Dbl): Dbl = if (x<b) x 
else go(bigComputation(x)) 
go(a)}
```

The actual algorithm could be recursive or have a `while` loop.

The user wants to update the stopping parameter *b* while the algorithm is running. (The reason could be to speed-up convergence or  to improve solutions, if a good *b* is unknown beforehand.)
The change is applied  the sooner, the better - ideally, at the next iteration.

**Q:** What would  a functional solution be? If such updating is against FP, what's the least bad non-FP design? (A small performance hit is fine, if the code is cleaner.)

There's a discussion of an FRP approach at http://sodium.nz/t/how-can-an-iterative-algorithm-be-controlled-dynamically-with-sodium/333/5, which doesn't fully solve it at the moment of writing.

Comment: The guy at that other post got it right: *"Functions running inside Sodium logic are atomic and referentially transparent (pure) so the idea of stopping the algorithm through an external state change doesn't exist in the Sodium universe."*

Comment: Yes, but he also suggested a possible solution based on CellLoop. So what's the  least bad non-FP solution to this update requirement?

Comment: Alas, I lack sufficient Sodium knowledge to know the answer to that.  You might want to be a bit more patient and wait for that other guy to answer.

Comment: A solution doesn't have to be Sodium specific.

Comment: If you're not constrained to Sodium's referential transparency preferences, then simply go with a mutable solution to the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't the usual approach be is to have separate threads for this? I presume that many command line server programs out there would be busy doing their own thing in the main thread & a separate thread will be waiting to be fed I/O, usually via the command line. While waiting, this latter thread would have no bearing on the main thread, until it is fed I/O & it interrupts the main thread, initiating the necessary updates.

Comment: @Dehbop That's similar to my current solution.  User updates are from a javaFX GUI on the "FX Thread", while the algorithm is running on a separate thread. After each iteration, the algorithm polls the current stopping parameter. My concern is how to best mitigate the fact that the algorithm is not a pure function. Might be no clean solution though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply pass a cancellation token into the function and have it check whether cancelation has been requested at each iteration.

However, this is obviously not a functional approach as the user would request the cancelation and thus inject state into the function.

Perhaps if you know the cancelation requirements in advance you can specify it as a function itself, (runningtime > 50,000) and get back to the functional paradigm

Comment: That's very interesting - thanks!   Instead of modelling the whole algorithm, with N iterations, as a "big" function, perhaps I could model  N calls of an  "iteration" function, each time with new parameters?  Then the mutability is pushed to the outside of the system, and is less bad.

Comment: Actually, the cancellation tokens seem a bit similar to how concurrency works in javafx. A `Task` implementing a computation has `isCancelled()` method, which it checks periodically. So we could implement an iteration in a `Task`, and have a `ScheduledService` control the iterative optimisation overall.

Comment: yes, exactly. not sure if you would have to explicitly check or not.

Answer (score 0):

This would imply to pause the algorithm change the values check the coherency and validity of the values and then continue. The reason for pause is that the change does not happen in the middle of the iteration. The validity must be ensured lets say the value cannot be negative or something else.